# How to change font of a row or a specific cell in a generated Excel through PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to create an Excel but unfortunately I am unable to change font of a specific cell or a specific row. I am even unable to make it bold.

I did anyhow change the entire Excel's font and size through

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial');
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(14);
```

I tried this but nothing seems to work:-

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getComment('A1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

Also any idea how I can increase the Series' font of a chart?

I'll be thankful of any assistance.

Best

Comment: the 2nd one should be:`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:E1')->getFont()->setBold(true);`

Comment: first one: `$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()
    ->setName('Arila')
    ->setSize(14);`

Comment: First one gives some sort of error and blankout the whole screen.

Answer (score 9):

I'm assuming you're using the latest version (v1.8.0). You have different options depending on the outcome you want to achieve:

To set the style for the entire workbook:

```
$phpExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()
    ->setName('Arial')
    ->setSize(14)
    ->setBold(true);
```

To apply a custom style to a single cell (or a range of cells):

```
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Here is an example:

$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();

```
// set the font style for the entire workbook
$phpExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()
    ->setName('Arial')
    ->setSize(14)
    ->setBold(true);

// custom style with different font than the global one
$styleArray = array(
    'font'  => array(
        'bold' => true,
        'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
        'size'  => 15,
        'name' => 'Verdana'
    ));

// create some cells
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->setValue('Hello world');
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A2')->setValue('Hello again');
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A3')->setValue('Goodbye');

// apply custom style to single cell
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

And the result will be something like this (notice the first cells have the global style while the A3 cell has the custom style):

[image]